# Is there a way to restore access to EC2 instance when SSH key gives error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

My AWS account was suspended when my credit card expired and I updated the card in an hour. The access to my account was restored. But when I started my EC2 server, and tried to connect with SSH it gave an error saying `Key not recognised`.

I tried to follow the steps provided by AWS support to attach my volume to another server, reset the SSH permissions and re-attach volume to my original server. But on attaching volume to new server and mounting it, I found that the user directory (/home/ubuntu) was missing along with the /var/www directory from apache 2. So I have been unable to reset the SSH access.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What appears in the debug log if you use `ssh -vvv`?

Comment: maybe the instance type had an ephemeral disk and this went away.  You don't say what the instance type was